# Prevent half-pixels in InDesign CS5

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign for web design and I'd love to be able to lock all resizing and moving to pixel increments - is there a way to do this?

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: go to preferences/general. at the top is the keyboard increment field. put in your measurement.

Comment: Although setting the keyboard increments to pixels helps a lot, that's not really the issue - it's more to do with when InDesign automatically spaces things out, it would be nice to never have it size or separate something to less than a pixel.